# Writing and Reading an ArrayList that uses multiple constructors and multiple values per ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I am trying to write my Arraylist into a text file and read that file back into my ArrayList.

I've written out the ArrayList using:

```
private static void saveFile(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs){
        File fileName = new File("VehicleList.txt"); 


        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for (int i = 0; i < vehs.size(); i++){
                output.write(vehs.get(i).toString());
                output.newLine();
            }

            output.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file");
        }
    }
```

But i am having trouble in reading the file back to fill in the ArrayList.

This is the code that i used to read back to the ArrayList:

```
  private static void readVFile(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("VehicleList.txt"));

    try {

        Object obj = null;
        while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
            if (obj instanceof Vehicle) {
            Vehicle v = (Vehicle) obj;
            vehs.add(v);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        ois.close();
    }



 }
```

This ArrayList takes 2 constructors in adding to it.

Constructors:

```
public PremiumVehicle(String vehicleID, String description, double dailyRate, int odometer, int allowance, int serLength, int lastOdo) //subclass

public Vehicle(String vehicleID, String description, double dailyRate, int odometer) //Superclass
```

Adding into ArrayList Example:

```
ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

vehs.add(new Vehicle("QJT123", "Starlet 99", 35.0, 190000));
vehs.add(new PremiumVehicle("TUX132", "BWM 05  ", 90.0, 12000, 100, 10000, 5000));
```

When i try to read the file back, it returns to me " StreamCorruptedException: Invalid stream header: 76656879". How do i read back the text file that i've just written into the ArrayList? Thanks for help in advance.

EDIT

I've tried using `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` but now it isn't recording what it is suppose to.

Edited Serialisation code:

```
private static void saveFile(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs){
        File fileName = new File("VehicleList.txt"); 


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i = 0; i < vehs.size(); i++){
                oos.writeObject(vehs.get(i));
            }

            oos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file");
        }
```

}

Comment: You can't serialize Objects via `toString()`. Use `ObjectOutputStream` instead

Comment: @SilverNak I've never used that before, do you mind giving me a brief example on how to use it?

Comment: @SilverNak I've tried using `ObjectOutputStream` however its not recording what i wasn't it to record. Instead it records the exceptions thrown such as `java.io.NotSerializableException` , `java.io.ObjectStreamException`. Maybe its something wrong with my loop?

Comment: The classes seem to be not serializable. The class delaration should look like this:
`public class Vehicle implements Serializable`. This is a marker interface, which has no methods to implement.